# Query about Virtio PMD in DPDK

Tags: virtualization, dpdk, vfio

I have few queries regarding DPDK's virtio driver when used on ARM machine. We do unbind virti-pci driver(of guest Kernel) from virto-net device emualted by QEMU, and then bind it to VFIO-PCI driver(of guest Kernel) but I didn't understand why we bind virtio-net device to VFIO-PCI driver?

In normal world, VFIO is used to assign device to guest but how it work in case of virtio-pmd driver for DPDK?

Also, is it necessary  to have vhost-net in case of virtio-pmd and how it fit in there ?

Comment: By default for any virtio-net device is bind with virtio-pci. To make it available to UIO or any userspace one has to bind with virtio-pci. So is question, why we bind with `igb_uio` or `vfio-pci` to access virtio-net device?

Comment: Yes, question is why we bind virtio-net device to vfio-pci, is it like vfio-pci driver does device configuration, for instance access to PCI device config space and actual packet processing is done virto pmd of DPDK?

Comment: I assume the hint will help, `vrtio-pci` kernel driver allows the device configuration and conversion of virtio packets to SKB. while `igb_uio or vfio-pci` allows configuration and buffer copy or zero copy to user space as it is.